# How to deal with numeric 6 digit dates

Tags: date, asp-classic, vbscript, integer

I have a Calendar program, that reside on the server, this program stores the dates into the database in the format :

> YYYYMMDD

is there a "easy" way to manage these dates in asp? for example, let's assume we have the April 20th 2013 as a date:

```
20130420
```

we want to add 20 days to this date, so we want to produce:

```
20130510
```

any idea? is there a integerTOdate conversion in asp? or something i could use to add "days" to the number `20130420` ?

Comment: 20 days from 20130420 is 20130510 and not 20130509! :)

Comment: i don't really get the -1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this (untested):

```
Dim strDate, theDate, theDatePlusTwentyDays
Dim Year, Month, Day  

' The date is stored as a string...
strDate = "20130420"

' Extract the components of the date
Year  = Mid(strDate, 1, 4)
Month = Mid(strDate, 5, 2)
Day   = Mid(strDate, 7, 2)

' Convert the components of the date into a datetime object
theDate = DateSerial(Year, Month, Day)

' Add 20 days using DateAdd
theDatePlusTwentyDays = DateAdd("d", 20, theDate)
```

Comment: Allthough the errors on the `Dim Year = ...`, `Dim Month = ...` and `Dim Day = ...` (you cannot declare-and-assign in one go in VBScript, maybe you would want to correct it), I like this one better than Dave Rooks solution because of the date stored as a string (do not store anything else in integers than integers) and the use of `DateSerial`.

Comment: @AutomatedChaos - Cheers! Will update. It's been a while since doing anything in VBScript.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can use the `DateAdd` function

```
Response.Write(DateAdd("d",1,Now()))
```

You need to format your date first though into something like

```
<%
dim _dateOnServer
dim _formattedDate
dim _day
dim _month
dim _year

_dateOnServer = 20130420

_year = Left(_dateOnServer,4)
_month  =  Mid(_dateOnServer,5,2)
_day = Right(_dateOnServer,2)


_formattedDate =  _month &"-"& _day &"-"& _year

dim _newDate
_newDate =  DateAdd("d",20, _formattedDate )

_day = Left(_newDate,2)
_month  =  Mid(_newDate,4,2)
_year = Right(_newDate,4)

dim _newDateFormat
_newDateFormat = _year & _month & _day

%>
```

Answer (score 1):

A solution that enables full control over order and format...

```
strDay = Day(Date)
strMonth = Month(Date)
strYear = Year(Date)
strHours = Hour(Now)
strMins = Minute(Now)
strSecs = Second(Now())
    if len(strMonth) = 1 then
        strMonth = "0" & strMonth
    end if
    if len(strDay) = 1 then
        strDay = "0" & strDay
    end if
    if len(strHours) = 1 then
        strHours = "0" & strHours
    end if
    if len(strMins) = 1 then
        strMins = "0" & strMins
    end if
    if len(strSecs) = 1 then
        strSecs = "0" & strSecs
    end if

strDateAdded = strYear & "-" & strMonth & "-" & strDay
strDateAddedTime = strDateAdded & " " & strHours & ":" & strMins
```

Using this method you have complete control over the order and even when running your web app in different time zones, you still maintain DD/MM format... or whatever order you want such as MM-DD-YY (by reordering and trimming the year). Personally I prefer YYYY-MM-DD because sorting by ASC and DESC is a lot easier to work with, ie: easier to read because all rows will have the same number of characters like:

```
2013-04-01 03:15
2013-04-09 10:15
2013-04-22 07:15
2013-04-23 10:15
2013-04-23 10:60
2013-10-25 12:01
2013-10-25 12:59
```

Instead of:

```
2013-4-1 3:15
2013-4-9 10:15
2013-4-22 7:15
2013-4-23 10:15
2013-4-23 10:60
2013-10-25 12:1
2013-1-25 12:59
```